# I am on Manjaro, and I am setting it up for JDBC, I have installed mariadb, mariadb-jdbc but I am not able to locate the /etc/my.conf file

Tags: mysql, java, manjaro

I have installed Mariadb and I have done everything by reading the documentation. Mariadb is running and I installed maria-jdbc after that.
Here is what I did

```
paru -Syu mariadb
mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql
sudo systemctl enable mysqld && sudo systemctl start mysqld
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

After this I installed mariadb-jdbc

```
paru -S mariadb-jdbc
```

Now this is where the problem begins. In the documentation I am being asked to
uncomment skip networking and then edit the bind address. The location of this file is supposed to be in **/etc/mysql/my.cnf**, but I have **/etc/my.cnf** and there is **/etc/my.cnf.d**.

```
#skip-networking

bind-address = *
```

I did grep for the required variables in the **my.cnf.d**,

```
/etc/my.cnf.d  grep skip-networking *                                                                                                                                                                

client.cnf.pacsave:skip-networking
enable_encryption.preset.pacsave:skip-networking
mysql-clients.cnf.pacsave:skip-networking
s3.cnf.pacsave:skip-networking
server.cnf.pacsave:skip-networking
spider.cnf.pacsave:skip-networking
```

Where should I add the things asked in the documentation, I do not know which file to edit. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, you'll find MariaDB's configuration file at the following location:

```
/etc/my.cnf
```

If it's not there you can use mysqld to look for the configuration file by running the following command:

```
/usr/libexec/mysqld --help --verbose
```

You'll get a lot of text back. The first part describes the options that you can send to the server when you launch it. The second part is all of the configuration information that was set when the server was compiled.

Near the start of the output, find a couple lines that look similar to the following lines:

Default options are read from the following files in the given order:

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

The server works down the list until it finds a configuration file.

Credit: https://docs.rackspace.com/support/how-to/configure-mariadb-server-on-centos/